# Fazendo operações/manuseando o DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

A ideia é o usuário digitar em um `textbox` a `horaEntrada` e em outro a `horaSaida` em que no caso essas 2 variáveis deveriam ter o formato "HH:mm" horas e minutos, apenas, depois disso pelo método `get` e `set` ali iriam atribuir as variáveis que eu falei em cima, apos isso eu criei o método `TempoPermanencia` em que o intuito é fazer uma subtração entre as horas e os minutos dessas variáveis para poder exibir o tempo que a pessoa ficou estacionada na tela do computador

Segue o código:

```
    private string placa, modelo;
    private DateTime horaEntrada, horaSaida;

    public string Placa
    {
        get { return placa; }
        set { placa = value; }
    }

    public string Modelo
    {
        get { return modelo; }
        set { modelo = value; }
    }

    public DateTime HoraEntrada
    {
        get { return horaEntrada; }
        set { horaEntrada = value; }
    }

    public DateTime HoraSaida
    {
        get { return horaSaida; }
        set { horaSaida = value; }
    }

    public DateTime TempoPermanencia()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que deseja. Estabeleça critérios claros. Deve pegar o que? Fazer? Que resultado deseja? Coloca onde? Esse código indica alguma coisa? Que parte dele é útil para o problema?

Comment: Vou pegar horaEntrada e horaSaida e fazer o seguinte: pegar as horas de horaSaida e subtrair com as horas de horaEntrada depois a mesma coisa com os minutos, para que assim eu retorne outro DateTime com as horas e os minutos que a pessoa ficou no lugar, colocar no método TempoPermanencia, indica sim, o tempo que uma pessoa ficou estacionada, gostaria de saber também como declarar para que um DateTime só aceite formatos em horas e minutos, grato.

Comment: Já mudou em relação ao que está descrito na pergunta. `DateTime` não serve para isso. Vou tentar fazer algo que seja útil. Como a data e hora é entrada? Tem certeza que vai descartar as outras informações que não hora e minuto?

Comment: Sim, apenas hora e minuto

Comment: São entradas sim senhor tbm.

Comment: Não vai ter data não

Comment: Está cada vez mais confuso.

Comment: Deixe eu lhe explicar melhor

Comment: A ideia é o usuário digitar em um textbox a horaEntrada e em outro a horaSaida em que no caso essas 2 variáveis deveriam ter o formato "HH:mm" horas e minutos, apenas, depois disso pelo metodo get e set ali iriam atribuir as variaveis que eu falei em cima, apos isso eu criei o metodo TempoPermanencia em que o intuito é fazer uma subtração entre as horas e os minutos dessas variaveis para poder exibir o tempo que a pessoa ficou estacionada na tela do computador, compreendeu ?

Comment: Seria melhor [edit] a pergunta e consolidar tudo isso de forma única. Estou fazendo uma resposta, mas alguns pontos eu não sei como resolver porque não tenho o requisito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para calcular a diferença basta fazer uma subtração, assim:

```
public TimeSpan TempoPermanencia() => HoraSaida - HoraEntrada;
```

Isso produzirá um [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que é exatamente o que precisa. [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), ao contrário do que muita gente pensa é apenas um ponto no tempo, nada mais, portanto um momento de entrada ou de saída é um ponto no tempo. Um período, uma quantidade de tempo dispendido em alguma coisa é representado por um `TimeSpan`. Leia a documentação dele para saber como usá-lo, pegar o tempo armazenado das diversas possíveis.

O ideal seria não considerar apenas a hora e o minuto. Não pode ser que a saída ocorre no dia seguinte? Não há a menor chance de isso ocorrer? Faz tanta diferença desconsiderar os segundos? Se os segundos não são importantes, não seria interessante que eles fossem descartados na entrada de dados? Até seria possível fazer isso na propriedade, mas teria que usar critérios claros. Sem requisitos certos, nenhum código será produzido certo.

Fiz uma solução mais "completinha" que não garanto que faz exatamente o que deseja, faltam critérios para resolver certas situações, por exemplo, no teste feito pode dar 1 hora e 43 minutos, ou 1 hora e 44 minutos, funciona, mas está sem critério claro se é isso mesmo que deve ocorrer. Nem testei. Mexer com data e hora é bem mais complicado do que parece. Cortei a informação supérflua na propriedade, mas poderia ter armazenado tudo e fazer essa conta de corte só na hora do cálculo.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objeto = new AlgumaClasse();
        objeto.HoraEntrada = DateTime.Now;
        objeto.HoraSaida = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(43).AddSeconds(22);
        WriteLine($"Permaneceu {(objeto.TempoPermanencia().ToString(@"hh\:mm"))}");
    }
}

class AlgumaClasse {
    public string Placa { get; set; }
 
    public string Modelo { get; set; }

    private DateTime horaEntrada;
    public DateTime HoraEntrada {
        get => horaEntrada;
        set {
            var tempo = default(DateTime).Add(value.TimeOfDay); //corta data
            horaEntrada = tempo.AddSeconds(-tempo.Second); //corta segundos
        }
    }

    private DateTime horaSaida;
    public DateTime HoraSaida {
        get=> horaSaida;
        set {
            var tempo = default(DateTime).Add(value.TimeOfDay);
            horaSaida = tempo.AddSeconds(-tempo.Second);
        }
    }
    public TimeSpan TempoPermanencia() => HoraSaida - HoraEntrada;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NhVzS1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uLGp1F). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Stays.cs).

Comment: É apenas um exercício do meu curso em que especificamente pede apenas horas e minutos, mas você tem razão, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Bem completa @bigown, mas o cara vai ter que explicar isso pro professor, acho que ele está iniciando. Mas muito boa como sempre suas respostas

Comment: @Murilo não está nem perto de ser ideal, tem várias coisas que não funcionam bem na "vida real". Ou requisito dado é complexo demais para ele, ou ele vai se virar com o que foi postado aqui. De qualquer forma, sempre que a pessoa não entende algo pode fazer uma nova pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Isso ai! Nao te dei +1 ainda que já acabou minha cota do dia.

Comment: @Murilo mas eu dou na sua :P

Comment: @bigown valeu mestre, eu nao preciso explicar não, é uma revisão para a prova e provavelmente o professor nem deve olhar, mas eu gosto de aprender uma coisa ou outra principalmente aqui, pois vocês que respondem mais frequentemente tem respostas bem completas, coisa que no manual da microsoft fica um pouco confuso, o que vale é o aprendizado, depois eu ainda fiz uma operação juntando double com o TimeSpan, nos trancos e barrancos a gente aprende ;)

Answer (score 2):

Eu entendi o que você quer.

Se você fizer `HoraEntrada - HoraSaida` o retorno será um `TimeSpan`

Os campos `HoraEntrada` e `HoraSaida` podem ser `DateTime`, faz sentindo, pois o carro entra/sai num dia e hora

Deve mudar o tempo de permanência

```
public TimeSpan TempoPermanencia()
{
    return HoraSaida - HoraEntrada;
}
```

Também pode ser

```
return HoraSaida.Substract(HoraEntrada);
```

Com o objeto `TimeSpan`você pode formatar com hh:mm, também tem `TotalDays`, `TotalHours`, etc

Para exibir seria algo assim:

```
TempoPermanencia().ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
```

Comment: deu errado o ToString, parece que não aceita-se o \

Comment: faltou algo. Editei. Faltou um @

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo...

Comment: O @ serve para algo especifico ?

Comment: Server pra dar "escape" na string. A barra invertida deve ser usada assim: \n ou \r por exemplo. Se quiser ela no literal deve usar o @ antes de "abrir" a string